# Detect notification click when app is in background or killed

Tags: android, bundle, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I want to know how app starts while it was in the background or killed when notification arrived.

I've set the `intent` to open the specific activities based on the received data in the notification.

```
if (moduleId == 1) {
    intent = new Intent(this, SchemesActivity.class);

} else if (moduleId == 2) {
    intent = new Intent(this, ProcedureActivity.class);

} else {
    intent = new Intent(this, NotificationsActivity.class);
}

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

I know when android app is in the background or killed and when notification arrives, app starts from launcher screen upon notification click.

Below is my code in splash screen to handle notification when app is killed/in background

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    int moduleId = bundle.getInt("Module_id");
    Intent intent;

    if (moduleId == 1) {
        intent = new Intent(this, SchemesActivity.class);

    } else if (moduleId == 2) {
        intent = new Intent(this, ProcedureActivity.class);

    } else {
        intent = new Intent(this, NotificationsActivity.class);
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(intent));
    finish();
} else {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, 1500);
}
```

But when I start app from launcher icon instead of tap on notification, it is still start specific screen because of bundle data received from notification. I don't want to do that. Start specific screen only when tap on notification. How can I do that?